# Как грамотно спроектировать маршруты?

Tags: php, laravel, маршрутизация

**Если 3 страницы:**

1. Список произведений.
2. Список коллекций.
3. Список цветов.

**Логика:**

Со страницы производителя можно перейти на страницу со списком всех коллекций этого производителя или на страницу со списком всех цветов этого производителя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если мы перешли на страницу со списком всех цветов этого производителя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если мы перешли на страницу со списком всех коллекций этого производителя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Со страницы со списком всех коллекций этого производителя можно перейти конкретно в определенную коллекцию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что есть сейчас:**

```
// Список всех производителей.
/manufacturers

// Цвета определенного производителя.
/manufacturers/{id}/colors

// Коллекции определенного производителя.
/manufacturers/{id}/collections

// Цвета определенной коллекции.
/manufacturers/{id}/collections/{id}/colors
```

Почему-то кажется, что есть более правильное решение. Мне не нравится, что когда мы получаем цвета определенной коллекции — мне нужно принимать в методе два параметра, хотя используется только второй (цвета у меня связаны только с коллекциями). Вторая проблема в том, что `/manufacturers/{вот сюда можно написать что угодно и это будет работать}/collections/{id}/colors`.

Контроллер который отвечает за цвет — один. В итоге нужно городить проверки, чтобы понять, это `id` производителя или коллекции. Я точно делаю что-то не так.

Comment: А вложенные разделы в адресе страницы - это обязательное условие? Нельзя сделать просто /manufacturer/{id}, /colors/{id} ... и т.д.?

Comment: @ИщуPHP-разработчикаВолгоград Обязательных условий нет. Если использовать ваш пример, то когда того понять, что именно нужно показать? Цвета производителя или цвета коллекции.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** 
* Список всех производителей.
* контроллер: manufacturers 
* метод: index
*/ 
/manufacturers

/** 
* Цвета определенного производителя.
* контроллер: manufacturers 
* метод: colors
*/ 
/manufacturers/colors/{id_manufacturer}

/** 
* Коллекции определенного производителя.
* контроллер: manufacturers 
* метод: collections
*/ 
/manufacturers/collections/{id_manufacturer}

/** 
* Цвета определенной коллекции.
* контроллер: collections
* метод: colors
*/ 
/collections/colors/{id_collectionsr}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::prefix('manufactures')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', "ControllerName@FunctionName); 

    Route::get('{manufacture}/colors', 'ControllerName@FunctionName'); // +  в аргументе функции указываешь что это класс App\Manufacture, это называется бинд модели

})
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding
И не надо будет городить проверки